# Deleted a Service Application did not remove the database in SQL HA

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

We are new to SQL HA and have the SharePoint Service Databases (Except Usage & Health) in a SQL HA Availability Group and they are Synchronized.

I went to remove the Machine Translation Database so I can Re-provision it again, but the Database did not delete.  No error was thrown when I deleted it in Central Administration.  Can someone tell me why this is the case.  Is there a different procedure when deleting Databases through SharePoint when using SQL HA ?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually delete the databases from AlwaysON groups, Because when SharePoint trying to delete the database from Always on group it throws this error:

```
11/29/2017 14:47:46.97  PowerShell.exe (0x56C4)                     0x5EC0  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880j    High        SqlError: 'The operation cannot be performed on database "KrossFarm_DB" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 1468 State: 1 Class: 16 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 1 Server: 'KFSQL1'   e3b7319e-8df1-702b-624d-cb2e359970ba
11/29/2017 14:47:46.97  PowerShell.exe (0x56C4)                     0x5EC0  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880j    High        SqlError: 'ALTER DATABASE statement failed.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 5069 State: 1 Class: 16 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 1 Server: 'KFSQL1' e3b7319e-8df1-702b-624d-cb2e359970ba
11/29/2017 14:47:46.97  PowerShell.exe (0x56C4)                     0x5EC0  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880j    High        SqlError: 'Cannot drop database "KrossFarm_DB" because it is currently in use.'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 3702 State: 4 Class: 16 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 1 Server: 'kfsql1'  e3b7319e-8df1-702b-624d-cb2e359970ba
11/29/2017 14:47:46.97  PowerShell.exe (0x56C4)                     0x5EC0  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        5586    Critical    Unknown SQL Exception 1468 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  The operation cannot be performed on database "KrossFarm_DB" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.  ALTER DATABASE statement failed.  Cannot drop database "KrossFarm_DB" because it is currently in use. e3b7319e-8df1-702b-624d-cb2e359970ba
```

You have to manually remove it from AlwaysON group then delete it from both nodes.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a service in Central Administration, there is a checkbox that marks if you want the databases associated with the services deleted aswell. Default answer is unchecked. The purpose is to allow Admin to recreate the service and attach existing database. If this happend to you, you can just delete the database from SQL Server Manager.

Comment: I had it checked to delete the database.